# Как открыть текстовый файл для просмотра или что не так в программном коде

Tags: vb.net

Как открыть текстовый файл для просмотра или что не так в программном коде

Код:

```
private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim Name As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 as OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
        Name = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        FileOpen(1, Name, OpenMode.Input)
    Else
        MsgBox("Имя файла не задано")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы приводить текст программы и ошибок <b>текстом</b>, а не графикой.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны создать экземпляр диалога перед использованием. Добавьте new:

```
Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
```